# How to fix broken/wrong wingpanel icon

Tags: wingpanel, icons

I installed Hipchat on my ElementaryOS system. I am on 0.3 Freya.
In the status bar is this icon:

[image: Wingpanel Icon]

Can I fix this myself or do I have to write the developer of hipchat?
I would be okay if the icon will be hidden, just like this it is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Install https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus
2. Edit hipchat4.desktop file in both places

   - /usr/share/applications
   - ~/.local/share/applications

Change Exec entry (should look like this):

Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /opt/HipChat4/bin/HipChat4